# What similar on Django-collectstatic for Pyramid?

Tags: python, django, pyramid, collectstatic

I need collect statics for different moduls in one place. Then to give this static to nginx from one place. Maybe it has already been implemented?

Comment: You probably don't need this, unless you're building the next facebook, or serve really huge files (next dropbox?). The overhead of invoking a thin layer of Python code when serving a static file is most likely absolutely negligible for your application. I'm finding Django's approach of insisting on not serving static assets in production quite annoying. YAGNI :)

Comment: @Sergey I really need it. In the project a lot of applications and a lot of static. Therefore looking for a solution. Statics is given through nginx, so i need something to collect it in one place. I was advised that's the solution - [webassets](http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid does not provide such a feature since it is not a convention-over-configuration framework. But there are a couple of ways to customize static asset URL generation for development and production environments. There is a newer configuration `media_location` that you could explore.

> To create such a circumstance, we suggest using the
>   pyramid.registry.Registry.settings API in conjunction with a setting
>   in the application .ini file named media_location. Then set the value
>   of media_location to either a prefix or a URL depending on whether the
>   application is being run in development or in production (use a
>   different .ini file for production than you do for development). This
>   is just a suggestion for a pattern; any setting name other than
>   media_location could be used.

- [Generating static asset URLs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html?highlight=media_location#generating-static-asset-urls)
- [Serving static files with Nginx](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html#step-3-serving-static-files-with-nginx-optional)
- [Pyramid Cookbook - Static Files](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/pylons/static.html)

Comment: >Pyramid does not provide such a feature since it is no convention-over-configuration framework.

I found a helper module - [van.static](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/van.static/1.3)

Comment: Maybe it can help me?

Comment: If it helps use it :-)